# Does the openGauss support the pgcrypto extension?

Tags: pgcrypto

Such as the title:Does the openGauss support the pgcrypto extension?

a.If not, what alternative method for hash calculation using SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, MD5, etc.?
b.If supported, how should you install this extension?

I have seen the relevant files(openGauss-server-master\contrib\pgcrypto) in the openGauss source code, but there is no contrib folder in the current official docker version and the online training environment. If it is executed in the database, the error is reported as follows:

If the following command:

```
omm=# create extension pgcrypto;
ERROR: could not open extension control file:No such file or directory
```

If the following command:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

In fact, it is installed in postgresql, not opengauss

Answer (score 0):

There are currently only these four functions in the opengauss pg_proc with the  like “crypt”

inside：
1.The gs_decrypt_aes128 has two parameters, the value and the key.
2.the gs_decrypt has three parameters, one more encryption type parameter than gs_decrypt_aes128, but there are only two encryption types, one aes128 and one sm4.